# Accessing the output of a function from another class

Tags: python, oop, kivy

what is the correct way of printing the output value of self.result2 inside class KivyCamera(Image) ?

```
class KivyCamera(Image):
    def __init__(self, capture, fps, **kwargs):
        super(KivyCamera, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        
        
class KivyCameraApp(App):
    def build(self):
  

    def switch_to_camera(self):
        self.sm.current = 'camera_screen'
        self.result2 = self.sm.current
```

Comment: The function needs to do `return self.result2`. Then you can assign that with `result = camera_app.switch_to_camera(camera)`

Comment: Why doesn't `switch_to_camera()` use the `instance` parameter?

Comment: Hi , i forgot to remove instance from the function , and about result = camera_app.switch_to_camera(camera) how should it be implemented inside the KivyCamera class ?

Comment: The instance parameter is irrelevant to the question. It still needs to return the result and then you can assign it when you call the function.

Comment: You can also just do `print(camera_app.result2)` after calling the function.

Comment: I've tried it but it doesn't work because of the self.sm.current

Comment: Why not? After you do `self.result2 = self.sm.current`, you can print `self.result2` to see the value.

Comment: Of course, the `KivyCamera` class needs a variable that references a `KivyCameraApp` instance. Please post a [mre] that shows how these two classes work together.